# How to define a kernel for filter2d in EMGU CV

Tags: emgucv

I would like to sharp an image by performing CvInvoke.Filter2d with a sharpening kernel:
{[-1,-1,-1],[-1, 9,-1],[-1,-1,-1]}

How do I can define this kernel in EMGU under C#?

I'm using EMGU version 4.3.0.3890

This is my code:

```
        // Load image
        Image<Bgr, Byte> img = null;
        img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"D:\Sample.png");
        
        // Convert the image to grayscale
        Image<Gray, float> gray = img.Convert<Gray, float>()
        .ThresholdBinary(new Gray(150), new Gray(255));

        // Add use of Filter2D here
```

Answer (score 4):

```
        // Load image
        Image<Bgr, byte> img = new Image<Bgr, byte>(@"path/img.jpg");

        // Convert the image to grayscale
        Image<Gray, byte> gray = img.Convert<Gray, byte>().ThresholdBinary(new Gray(150), new Gray(255));

        // Add use of Filter2D here
        CvInvoke.Imshow("GrayImage", gray);

        float[,] matrix = new float[3, 3] {
                      { 1, 1, 1 },
                      {  1, -9, 1},
                      { 1, 1, 1 }
                    };
        ConvolutionKernelF matrixKernel = new ConvolutionKernelF(matrix);

        var dst = new Mat(gray.Size, DepthType.Cv8U, 1);
        CvInvoke.Filter2D(gray, dst, matrixKernel, new Point(0, 0));

        CvInvoke.Imshow("FiltredImage", dst);

        CvInvoke.WaitKey(0);
```

PS:

- Preferably you have to use Mat and Matrix (if you need to access the pixels) and not image. --> source: https://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Working_with_Images
- By converting to gray level, it is necessary to take the type byte and not float

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm struggling with it for sometime now. First, I think that you swapped the location of the 'point' and the 'kernel'. Also, I keep getting the message "Message=OpenCV: src->size() == dst->size() && src->channels() == dst->channels()". If you have any ideas how to solve it, that would be great.

Comment: I rectifie new Solution

Comment: I'm still getting a failure...

Comment: I'm still getting the same failure. I added my code to the question. Maybe that will help. In addition, the point that I'm using is (-1, -1). Are you using a different point?

Comment: I update my answer

Comment: After changing the image to byte and using your last update it worked. :-) 
Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it very much!!!